# Silverlight to WPF: Windows authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, iis, silverlight

I am attempting to convert a Silverlight application to WPF.  I control web access to the Silverlight application and its APIs by requiring Windows Authentication in IIS.  This works well, even for non-local, non-domain computers accessing the app, as the user's web browser automatically prompts for the user's credentials.

I cannot figure out any way to have a WPF application running on a non-local, non-domain computer access these same remote web server APIs that are protected by Windows Authentication in IIS.  Does anyone have any code examples of how this might be done from a WPF application?

I need the WPF app to request the user's credentials, and use those credentials in accessing the WCF services running under an IIS site that has (only) Windows authentication enabled, from a non-domain computer.

Comment: You just need to wrap over the native calls to show the prompt, and libraries like [this](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-prompt-for-a-password-on-windows.htm) already exist.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the link.  I checked out the Meziantou.Framework.Win32.CredentialManager library, and it appears the it cannot do Windows credentials.  Additionally, the domain policy of the PC accessing our domain doesn't allow the saving of Windows credentials in Credential Manager, as a matter of group policy, so I cannot manually provide the credential for the WPF app to use.